# make a single heading for both mobile and desktop view with two different font sizes

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

In my application i want the heading to be in two different fonts-sizes for mobile view and desktop view

Here is what i achieved to do so and  it works!

```html
<h2 class="mb-0 d-none d-lg-block" >My APP Name Desktop</h2>
<h2 class="mb-0 d-block d-lg-none" style="font-size: medium;">My APP Name Mobile</h2>
```

But instead of using two h2 is there any way to combine both in a single heading other than media queries in css file.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you don't want to use media queries?

Comment: What do you mean by "*other than media queries in css file*"?  That's a bit like asking "*how do I do responsive CSS without doing responsive CSS*".

Comment: i know best way to use is media queries but wondering if there are any boot strap classes to achieve it

Comment: When you write you want it to be 2 different fonts, you really should state that you mean "font sizes", else it can be one is "Arial" the other "Verdana"

Comment: i have updated accordingly apologies incorrect info

Comment: "*any boot strap classes to achieve it*" - Bootstrap already scales `<h2>` responsively ... you don't need to do anything.  `<h2>Headline</h2>` will change font size depending on viewport size.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a fully responsive way of declaring your font-size. One way to do this is using `font-size: clamp(value1, value2, value3)`.

The first value is the **minimum** value - the font-size will never be lower than what you set here.

The second value is the **preferred** value. The element will try to set the font-size to this value.

The last value is the **maximum** value. The element's font size will never exceed this.

As for setting the values, I suggest using either `em`, `rem` or `vw`-units for a fully responsive effect. Using the `em`-unit on the `font-size` property allows setting the font size of an element relative to the font size of its parent. When the size of the parent element changes, the size of the child changes automatically.

**Read more about `em` & `rem` on the `font-size`-property:** https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-em-and-rem-units-in-css/

Play a bit around with the values! Try resizing the browser in a new tab with the example snippet and see the effect of how powerful `clamp()` is.

```css
body {
  width: 800px;
  font-size: 40px;
}

div {
  width: 50%;
  font-size: clamp(0.5em, 8vw, 8em);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    Font size
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This is awesome!  I've never seen clamp().

Answer (score 0):

Use this:
JS Code

```
function device() { if (navigator.userAgent.match("Android") || (navigator.userAgent.match("Macintosh") && navigator.maxTouchPoints > 0) || navigator.userAgent.match("iOS") || navigator.userAgent.match("iPhone") || navigator.userAgent.match("iPad") || navigator.userAgent.match("BlackBerry") || navigator.userAgent.match("iPod") && navigator.maxTouchPoints > 0) { mobile = true; console.log("Is mobile device: <TRUE>") } else { mobile = false; console.log("Is mobile device. <FALSE>"); return mobile; } }  //Mobile/Or not?
If (device() == true) {
document.getElementById('title').style.fontSize = 'medium'
}
else {
document.getElementById('title').style.fontSize = '20pt'
}
```

HTML Code

```
<div style=font-family:sans-serif; id=title>Hello World :-)</div>
```

Or using CSS

```
div#title {
font-size: calc(20vw + 20vh / 2.5)
}
```